# What database objects (tables, indexes, procs, etc) are added to db with diagraming support?

Tags: sql-server

When you click on "Database Diagrams" in SSMS, it will ask to enable diagramming support, which means that a number of objects will be added to the db.

Is there a list of all those objects added to the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head I don't know but to find out you could setup a SQL Server Profiler trace to record and inspect the activity that occurs when you install support for Database Diagrams.

Comment: I got an db update proc, that should preserve, eg skip, diagramming support tables. I need it for 2k5-2k8R2, and it looks like the list is "fluid". If there is no official list, I'll have to do what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Books Online article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189279(v=SQL.90).aspx):

1. sysdiagrams table
2. sp_alterdiagram stored procedure
3. sp_creatediagram stored procedure
4. sp_dropdiagram stored procedure
5. sp_renamediagram stored procedure
6. fn_diagramobjects function
7. sp_helpdiagrams stored procedure
8. sp_helpdiagramsdefinition stored
   procedure
9. sp_upgraddiagrams stored procedure

Comment: I just checked against a DB where I have the diagrams installed and I don't see anything like that.

Comment: Not in 2008. In 2005 I have dtproperties, dt_XXXX stored procs.